How many ways IIlich can write numbers from $1$ to $5$ in the table so that frog reaches the rightmost cell?

Ilich wants to write one of the numbers from $1$ to $5$ in each cell of the following table (the numbers can be repeated).
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$
After writing the numbers, a frog starts at the leftmost cell of the table. In each step, the frog sees the number in the cell and jump to
the right cells according to that number (for instance if the number is $1$ the frog jumps to the adjacent right cell). If the number is so large that the frog has no cell to jump, it will not jump. How many ways Ilich can write numbers on the table so that after a number of steps the frog reaches the rightmost cell in the table?
$1)625\quad\quad2)5625\quad\quad3)3125\quad\quad4)32\quad\quad5)6480$

I have solved this problem using brute force:
Noting that the rightmost cell can have any numbers from $1$ to $5$ we can ignore it and multiply the final result by $5$. Assuming the first number is $5$, there are $5^4$ ways to fill in the four middle cells. If the first number is $4$, there are $5^3$ ways to fill in the next three cells and the fifth cell should be $1$. If the first cell is $3$ and the fourth cell is $2$ there are $5^3$ ways to fill in the remaining cells and if the fourth cell is $1$ we can fill the remaining two cells in $5^2$ ways, and so on. Here is my answer counting all the possible cases:
$$5\times(625+125+125+25+125+25+25+5+125+25+25+5+36)=6480$$
While my approach works, I am interested to see other methods to solve this problem.

Having had the benefit of seeing the previous answers, here is a short one which I might not have found otherwise.
Place a digit from $1$ to $5$ in square $6$ ($5$ choices).  Write an $X$ in square $1$,  indicating the frog lands there.  In each of squares $2$ through $5$, either write an $X$, indicating the frog lands there, or a digit from $1$ to $5$ ($6$ choices).  Now go back and replace each $X$ with the distance to the next $X$ or, in the case of the last $X$, with the distance to square $6$.
This process yields $5 \times 6^4$ ways to get the frog to the final square.

I knew there had to be an elegant way of getting there, very nice

The frog needs to jump from some cells that add up to $6-1=5$.  We can place those cells and then fill in the other cells at will.  The number of cells the frog lands on will dictate how many other cells we can fill at will; thus, all we actually care about is, for each possible number of moves, how many total ways there are to get the frog to jump $5$ steps in that many moves.
We refer to the Twelvefold Way:  we have $5$ identical "steps" and $x$ marked "jumps", and we have to put at least one step on each pad, so we can use
$$\binom{5-1}{5-x}=\binom{4}{5-x}$$
to find the number of ways the frog can make $x$ leaps.
Then we have $6-x$ pads that have not been leapt from, and each can have any of $5$ different numbers, and $x$ can be anywhere from $1$ to $5$, for a final score of
$$\sum_{x=1}^5 5^{6-x}\binom{4}{5-x}$$
which comes out to
$$\begin{align}
&5^5\cdot\binom{4}{4}+5^4\cdot\binom{4}{3}+5^3\cdot\binom{4}{2}+5^2\cdot\binom{4}{1}+5^1\cdot\binom{4}{0}\\
=&3125\cdot1+625\cdot4+125\cdot6+25\cdot4+5\cdot1\\
=&3125+2500+750+100+5\\
=&6480
\end{align}$$
But as Calvin Lin points out in the comments, this actually can be done even more neatly if we break some stuff up and recognize the binomial theorem in there:
We have
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=1}^5 5^{6-x}\binom{4}{5-x}\\
=&5 \sum_{x=1}^5 5^{5-x}\binom{4}{5-x}\\
=&5 \sum_{x=1}^5 5^{5-x}1^x\binom{4}{5-x}\\
=&5 (5+1)^4
=5\cdot6^4=5\cdot1296=6480
\end{align}$$

As an aside, the final expression can easily be evaluated as $ 5 ( 1 + 5)^4 = 6480$.
